# how to set scrollable offset of a marker

Tags: leaflet

I create a marker with an icon, but the position of the icon is not in the top-right where the perfect place it should be, So how to set position offset for a marker.

I searched a while and found a raw [solution](http://embed.plnkr.co/LeNqz8/), it's not work after the a mouse scrolling. when I zoom in the map, the icon moves far beyond the original position.

here is my code

```js
const marker = L.marker(eaPoint.position, {
    icon: L.icon({
      iconUrl: ICONS.ruby,
      iconSize: [30, 40],
    }),
    riseOnHover: true,
    data: eaPoint.data,
  })
```

Comment: I think you're just missing `iconAnchor`. https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#icon-iconanchor

Comment: @IvanSanchez thank you, it works, I should have carefully read the documentation first.

Answer (score 1):

It works with the iconAnchor attribute, I should have read the documentation.

```js
const marker = L.marker(eaPoint.position, {
    icon: L.icon({
      iconUrl: ICONS.ruby,
      iconSize: [30, 40],
      iconAnchor: [0, 30]
    }),
    riseOnHover: true,
    data: eaPoint.data,
  })
```